# All Settings lost after restarting Ubuntu

Tags: boot

i m using Ubuntu 14.04 on u.s.b drive.each time i use Ubuntu ,all my previous activities lost from it and it starts up as newly installed o.s.please solve my problem.i have made changes several time but all of them lost,again and again...

Comment: You made a non-persistent install? If so see http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, that usually happens when you are using a guest account. If that's not the problem, there might be a problem with the startup options. Your most likely bet would be to use a different USB or a different Linux distro.